# Is there a standard way to add some approval procedure/or at least notification for changes in task groups/builds/etc.?

Tags: tfs, build, azure-devops, vnext

We had a few cases when:

1. Someone changes a [task group](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=vsts) (or build/release/whatever).
2. Makes some mistake.
3. Then publishes/saves it.
4. But doesn't notify anyone that such changes were made.
5. Some hours later some dependent build breaks because of those changes.
6. And we have to spend even more time trying to find what and when has changed as it is not often that simple to find out with external task groups.

What we want to have:

1. Ideally - some approval process for such changes. Kind of like code review, but for task groups/builds.
2. If not - then at least some way to receive notifications about changes in task groups and etc. we are interested in?

I found neither, and, honestly, doubt that such features are present in the TFS version we use (TFS 2018.2), but perhaps I've missed something.

Comment: I don't think it's possible, just give permissions to the right people...

Comment: Nice idea, kind of the way you get notifications when someone installs a marketplace task.  Unless they create the new version with a major version increment, you'll likely never know, depending on how many builds you have to update, you may have to pick the lesser of the two evils (no notification, or update any necessary builds).

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Well, they are right people, who have to be allowed to edit such items, just sometimes one rushes a bit too much and ... well, you understand what happens. Not that all bugs are shallow with another pair of eyes, but that at least helps a bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any workflow security or approval process for the groups. You could suggest that kind of feature on the [developercommunity](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21).  Restrict access to edit Task Groups to only those who understand how to bump the Task Group version.  That way at least you will keep backward compatibility across your builds unless that explicitly upgrade to that version.

There aren't any built in notifications, but you could create an automated process to send email notifications using PowerShell using the existing API.

1. Get the Id for the task group using the [taskgroups list api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/taskgroups/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)
2. Use the revisions api to get the history `_apis/distributedtask/taskgroups/{taskgroupid}/revisions`
3. Send an update for anything that edited today